Excel VBA - restarting a sequence of numbers
I have a worksheet that allows the user to enter data into specific cells and vba code that provides a sequence of numbers.
The sequence of numbers are in columns A and N and both start in row 7.
When the user hits the button the code creates a new blank line with the next number in the sequence ready for the user to enter the data.
Column A can start at 001 to 999 but must not go to 1000 and must have a "000" number format
Column N can start at 01 to 99 but must not go to 100 and must have a "00" number format.
Currently the code looks like this but it is missing an instruction to restart at "001" in column A and "01" in column N.
Any help would be much appreciated!
    IncreaseSeqNumber = Range("A8").Value
    IncreaseSeqNumber1 = Replace(IncreaseSeqNumber, "", "")
    IncreaseSeqNumber2 = IncreaseSeqNumber1 + 1
    IncreaseSeqNumber3 = IncreaseSeqNumber2
 
    Range("A7").Value = IncreaseSeqNumber3
    Range("A7").NumberFormat = "000"

    IncreaseCalSeqNumber = Range("N8").Value
    IncreaseCalSeqNumber1 = Replace(IncreaseCalSeqNumber, "", "")
    IncreaseCalSeqNumber2 = IncreaseCalSeqNumber1 + 1
    IncreaseCalSeqNumber3 = IncreaseCalSeqNumber2

    Range("N7").Value = IncreaseCalSeqNumber3
    Range("N7").NumberFormat = "00"


What's with the huge number of variables? Why can't you just use Range("A7").Value = Range("A8").Value + 1 (not considering the additional requirement)? Once you set the number format, there is no need to set it each time you call the sub. Please clarify by editing your post (not in the comments).

... and easy enough to add the reset:  Range("A7").Value = Range("A8").Value + 1 mod 1000

@ChrisMaurer Almost but it's rather Range("A7").Value = Range("A8").Value Mod 999 + 1 i.e. 998 Mod 999 + 1 = 999, 999 Mod 999 + 1 = 1, 1 Mod 999 + 1 = 2, ....

So you have IncreaseSeqNumber3 and IncreaseCalSeqNumber3... you can just check with an if-statement if they exceed your limit:
If IncreaseCalSeqNumber3 = 100 Then IncreaseCalSeqNumber3 = 1
.Cells(7, "N").Value = IncreaseCalSeqNumber3

As we can't see what is tied to IncreaseCalSeqNumber, maybe that is a better place for the check... it could even be as simple as listing current and previous, similar to the comments:
.Cells(8, "N").Value = IncreaseCalSeqNumber
If IncreaseCalSeqNumber = 99 then IncreaseCalSeqNumber = 0
.Cells(7, "N").Value = IncreaseCalSeqNumber+1

